# Pull Sitecore Project

Tags: xm-cloud

TBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBD

Comment: Hi @Ionut - I'm closing this because that question really can't be answered on SSE, its far to broad of a question with nuances to the answer. Please reach out to the partner enablement team and we can point you to the learning/training you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a developer and wish to contribute, then you should have access to source control (Github, AzDo etc. wherever you are managing your code).

You can have containerized setup locally that would host your Sitecore part. Your code repository (Front end + Back end - considering headless implementation) should be cloned locally and your changes should be deployed and verified on your local containers.

Content changes are managed through Serialization (Sitecore Content Serialization mostly). Content changes like Templates, Layouts, Renderings etc. should be maintained in Source code along with your code files.

Deployment Pipelines will deploy your changes to Upper Environment. Each environment will have following pipelines -

- Backend changes will be deployed to Sitecore XM Cloud environment.
- If you have headless implementation then you will have a separate deployment process for front end application as well (Ex. - Vercel in case of NextJs)

This will be needed for each environment and may vary as per your architectural setup.
Roughly it would look like this (This is not a recommendation, number of  environments may vary, few more service components may exist which are not shown here) -

[image]

I hope this clears the flow.